# How to modify the numerical decimals of my API?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fetch-api

I need the numerical data that the API returns to have two decimal places instead of three, that is, if it gives me a number: 140,444 it will be 140,44

What should I modify?

```js
function fetchData() {
  fetch("https://www.dolarsi.com/api/api.php?type=valoresprincipales")
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      const filteredOutput = data.filter((item) => {
        switch (item.casa.nombre) {
          case "Dolar Blue":
            return item;
            break;
          default:
            return null;
        }
      });
      let html = "";
      filteredOutput.forEach((item) => {
        html +=
          '<p class= "venta">  <small class= "ventaPrecio">VENTA</small><span</span><br>  $ ' +
          item.casa.venta +
          "</p>";
      });

      document
        .querySelector("#blueVenta")
        .insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", html);
    });
}
fetchData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning directly just return item.toFixed(2). This will give you 2 numbers after comma ;)

EDIT: adding pic so you can more clearly see how to fix your problem:

[image]

Comment: this is the right way of doing it. Where is the number you want to truncate? `item.casa.venta`? You should add the toFixed there. If that doesn't solve it, you're doing something else wrong. Try debugging the flow to see what's going on. Also, try doing this in the devtools console. You should get the desired value

Comment: When I add item.toFixed (2) .casa.venta it stops showing me the value directly.

Comment: because item is an object not a number, you should add `item.casa.venta.toFixed(2)`.

Comment: You should also be careful with possible null values, you can safe guard this by doing: ` (((item || {}).casa || {}).venta || 0).toFixed(2) or something like that